# Delaying or slowing down (TimeOut) a command in Discord JS

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to get my command to run slower, if that is the correct way to say it. :(

I think I have something, but its not working

What I am looking to do is wait for 1 second before each message is sent, as I have to send the message to over 500 guilds but don't want to be rate limited.

```
let i = 0;
data.message.client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => setTimeout(function Wait ()
{

   i += 1;
   if (guild.id && guild.systemChannel && guild.systemChannel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES"))
   {

      console.log(`Embed Message ${i} Sent to guild ${guild.id} - ${guild.name}`);
      return guild.systemChannel.send({"embed": {
         "color": 9514728,
         "description": `${data.announcement.message}`,
         "footer": {
            "text": "This is a test message"
         },
         "title": `${data.announcement.title}`
      }});

   }

}, 1000));
```

All this does is it waits for 1 second before sending all messages.

I have also tried:

```
let i = 0;
for (const guild of data.message.client.guilds.cache)
{

   setTimeout(function Wait ()
   {

      i += 1;
      if (guild.id && guild.systemChannel && guild.systemChannel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES"))
      {

         console.log(`Embed Message ${i} Sent to guild ${guild.id} - ${guild.name}`);
         return guild.systemChannel.send({"embed": {
            "color": 9514728,
            "description": `${data.announcement.message}`,
            "footer": {
               "text": "This is a test message"
            },
            "title": `${data.announcement.title}`
         }});

      }

   }, 1000);

}
```

Comment: Instead of waiting for `1000` why not try `i*1000`?

Comment: `i` is just used for my console log message, just so i can see how many it has sent. Its not used in the delay.

Comment: Correct and if you use it in the delay as I suggested it will send the messages as you want.

Comment: But then after the 5 mesage it would be `i=5` `i*1000 = 5000` and thats 5 second before sending, with 500 servers that means by the end it would be `i=499` `i*1000 = 499000`, so 499 seconds.
Unless im missing what you are saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have right now is you go through each 500 guildes at once and set delay of 1sec. After 1sec all 500 messages are sent.

What you need to do is send each message after previous message was sent.
Try this (assuming `data.message.client.guilds.cache` is an array):

```
let i = 0;

!function sendMessage ()
{
  const guild = data.message.client.guilds.cache[i++];
  if (guild.id && guild.systemChannel && guild.systemChannel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES"))
  {

    console.log(`Embed Message ${i} Sent to guild ${guild.id} - ${guild.name}`);
    guild.systemChannel.send({"embed": {
       "color": 9514728,
       "description": `${data.announcement.message}`,
       "footer": {
          "text": "This is a test message"
       },
       "title": `${data.announcement.title}`
    }});

  }
  if (i <= data.message.client.guilds.cache.length)
    setTimeout(sendMessage, 1000);
}();
```

Comment: nope, not an arrany, but i could pump it in to an array. Will try now

Comment: Well, than I hope you get the concept from this example. If you have to convert it into an array, do it outside of the function for performance. Just curious what type of object is than?

Comment: https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/collections.html

Dicsord.js classes them as collection.

Comment: And yea, i=you have gave me an idea and it might just work, thank you

Answer (score 1):

So this may not be the best way, but it works.

```
let i = 0;
const guilds = [];
for (const guild of data.message.client.guilds.cache)
{

   guilds.push(guild);

}

const wait = setInterval(function ()
{

   const guild = guilds.shift();

   i += 1;
   if (guild === undefined)
   {

      console.log(`Done all servers`);
      clearInterval(wait);

   }
   else if (guild[1].id && guild[1].systemChannel && guild[1].systemChannel.permissionsFor(guild[1].me).has("SEND_MESSAGES"))
   {

      console.log(`Embed Message ${i} Sent to guild ${guild[1].id} - ${guild[1].name}`);
      return guild[1].systemChannel.send({"embed": {
         "color": 9514728,
         "description": `${data.announcement.message}`,
         "footer": {
            "text": "This is a test message"},
         "title": `${data.announcement.title}`
      }});

   }

}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use setTimeOut and a promise.

```js
const sleep = (ms) =>  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
```

then running `sleep(MS)` will wait before continuing

```js
async function run() {
  const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

  console.log(1);
  await sleep(1000); // wait one second
  console.log(2);
  await sleep(1000); // wait one second
  console.log(3);
}

run()
```